# How to send request to get JSON file

Tags: jquery, json, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm tried to get json file from website. I tried BeautifulSoup library  but  was empty.

In DevTools  was not empty and there is a sample Jquery code:

```
$('#domtableweek').dataTable({
       "processing": true,
       "serverSide": true,
       "bSort": false,
       "bLengthChange": false,
       "pageLength": 10,
       ajax: {
           url: '/data/mal-domains-data',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'yafh4aGjo0S6SeTci6qv2PzlcEuTW7E8', 'time':'7-Day'}
       },
       "dataSource": ''
   });
```

So I tried this code

```
import requests

csrf = 'some_csrf_token'
cookie = 'some_cookie_id'
data = dict({'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'yafh4aGjo0S6SeTci6qv2PzlcEuTW7E8', 'time':'7-Day'})
url = 'https://minotr.net/data/mal-domains' 
headers = {'Cookie':cookie}

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)

print r.text
```

Result is:

```
 <p>You are seeing this message because this HTTPS site requires a &#39;Referer header&#39; to be sent by your Web browser, but none was sent. This header is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>
  <p>If you have configured your browser to disable &#39;Referer&#39; headers, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for HTTPS connections, or for &#39;same-origin&#39; requests.</p>
`
```

Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

So the thing is that you need to set a "Referer" header here.

```
headers = {'Cookie':cookie, 'Referer':'https://google.com/'}
```

Try this one

And to get JSON you have to use .json() method.

```
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers).json()
```

Comment: raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: It means that you got onto the wrong link with no JSON. Also it will raise a 403 error if you make a request, so check your settings and maybe set another referer link (the link from which you usually get onto the page that is requested by you).